# I need a way to give a sql authenticated user read access to a windows directory

Tags: sql-server, permissions, windows, linked-server

A SQL-authenticated user SBA_USER is selecting from a View which uses Linked Server which points to an Excel spreadsheet in the I:\Folder directory on a windows server.

Problem I have is that the access to the directory is controlled by Windows and the Login SBA_USER is not a Windows account.

I need a way to give SBA_USER read access to the directory I:\Folder. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is to create stored procedure that would select from a View

When creating stored procedure, use EXECUTE AS clause and set it to a Windows-authenticated account (grant all necessary permissions to this account, required to read from I:\Folder)

Grant execute on procedure to SBA_USER

This way when SBA_USER  executes procedure, procedure does select from View, from behalf of the Windows-authenticated account

Comment: Thanks, let me quickly try this

Comment: @AndleebHasan another thing to try - it may be possible to actually map SBA_user to Windows-auth login, in the Linked Server security settings. You know section where you do login mapping

Comment: I was under the impression that whenever SQL needed to access file while using a SQL Login, it uses the SQL Service account to do it... If you can, you could try to give access to your excel spreadsheet to the SQL service account

Comment: i tried to did that but i think i have less reputation 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'